# Return sorted sub-sequence of size k

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Do I need to run inner loop so this function can return `k` size increasing sub-sequence of an array. I did the following with the help of couple articles online. As of now as expected it returns longest sub-sequence.

```
function findKSizeSubSequence(array, k) {
    if(array.length < k) 
        return;
    var maxCount = 0, count = 0;
    var prev = array[0];
    var m = [];
    for(var i = 0;i < array.length;i++) {
        if(prev <= array[i]) {
            count++; 
            m.push(array[i]);                
        } else {
            count = 1;
        }
        if(count > maxCount) 
            maxCount = count;

        prev = array[i];
    }
    return m;
}
```

But what-if I only want it to return `k` size increasing sub-sequence.

Eg:

`findKSizeSubSequence([3,1,4,2,5,1,6,4,7], 4);` should return only `[3,4,5,6]`
`findKSizeSubSequence([3,1,4,2,5,1,6,4,7], 2);` should return only `[3,4]`

Comment: What about findLongestSubSequnce(array).slice(0, k), unless it must return the first match.

Comment: I don't think current implementation return longest increasing sub-sequence. Given [1,5,2,3,4], it returns [1,5,3,4]. You may look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

Answer (score 1):

Just add one array length check in loop. If length matches to k then just make an exit from loop.

E.g.:

```
function findKSizeSubSequence(array, k) {
    if(array.length < k) 
        return;
    var maxCount = 0, count = 0;
    var prev = array[0];
    var m = [];
    for(var i = 0;i < array.length;i++) {
        if(prev <= array[i]) {
            count++; 
            m.push(array[i]);   
            if(m.length === k){
                break;
            }

        } else {
            count = 1;
        }
        if(count > maxCount) 
            maxCount = count;

        prev = array[i];
    }
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But what-if I only want it to return k size increasing sub-sequence.

**Shortest answer** is

Replace

```
return m;
```

by

```
return m.slice(0,k);
```

It can **optimized a little more** by adding a check after `push` statement

```
    if(prev <= array[i]) {
        count++; 
        m.push(array[i]);                
        if ( m.length == k ) //this condition will stop the loop as soon as `k` elements have been pushed to `m`
        {  
           break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a diffferent style with early exit, if the count is reached.

```js
function findKSizeSubSequence(array, count) {
    var result = [array[0]];
    array.some(function (a) {
        if (a > result[result.length - 1]) {
            result.push(a);
            return result.length === count;
        }    
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(findKSizeSubSequence([3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 4, 7], 4));
console.log(findKSizeSubSequence([3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 4, 7], 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```